# Question related to DBMS_SQL.PARSE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query like

```
queryStr := 'SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM Table1 WHERE date_created >= ';
```

and then i see the following statement

```
DBMS_SQL.PARSE (cursor_handle, queryStr || ':date', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE (cursor_handle, 'date', dateVariable);
```

Now my question is, how come dbms_sql.parse is using the variable **:date** since there is no :date placeholder in the query i.e. **queryStr**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is equivalent to this:

```
DBMS_SQL.PARSE (cursor_handle,
                'SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 
                   FROM Table1 
                  WHERE date_created >= :date', 
                DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE (cursor_handle, 'date', dateVariable);
```

A query is parsed in the first statement. This statement has a bind variable (:date). The value of this bind variable is given in the second statement.

Comment: but my question is how come dbms_sql.parse knows that :date is going to be a place holder ?? I mean there is no :date place holder in original query. Original query just ended at **date_created >= **. Is it something automatically done?

Comment: secondly, when I am binding the :date variable, can use any other name like :date_check or :random_date or :placeholder ... would it bind after parsing?

Comment: @alee Well, `:date` is a bind variable because it is prefixed by ":", I don't know what else to say. `dbms_sql.parse` knows that elements prefixed by ":" are bind variables, this is part of the specification of `dbms_sql`.

Comment: @alee: you could use any other name (most likely restricted to 30 chars) as long as this other name is also used in the query. If your query is `SELECT :other_date FROM DUAL`, you will have to bind "other_date" to be able to run this query. Obviously misbinding would result in an error (trying to bind "date" instead of "other_date")

Comment: @Alee: When you call the `dbms_sql.parse` with the parameter `queryStr || ':date'` you are passing a string of `queryStr` concatenated with the string `':date'`. `dbms_sql.parse` does not have access to `queryStr` by itself.

Comment: oh my bad. I didn't notice that queryStr is being concatenated by || is dbms_sql.parse. now it makes sense to me :)